# Function and Derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives

If $$F(x)= (x-1)^{20} - (x-2)^{30}
\cdot(x-3)^{40}$$

The number of real roots of $F''(x)=0$ are?

$F''(x)$ - Second Derivative of $F(x)$.

I have worked it out by simply differentiating it and then finding the roots.

It turned out to be very  lengthy. Is there a better way to do this? 
Even a hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since you computed the second derivative (what you could have included in the post) which is a polynomial of degree $68$ ($F(x)$ being of degree $70$), you can notice that values such that $x=1,x=2,x=3$ seem to play a significant role (just as in $F(x)$).

By inspection $F''(1)$ is a very large negative number, $F''(2)$ is a relatively small positive number, $F''(3)$ is a large positive number and $F''(4)$ is a very large negative number. So, obviously, there is one root between $1$ and $2$ as well as another between $3$ and $4$.

What about the other roots ? This is a question.